# How to "Click" a button on pressing enter button on PrimeNG and Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a form with a "Login" button on Angular with PrimeNG. The structure is basically like this

```
  <div class="Login">

          <label>Email</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="username" pInputText [(ngModel)]="username" />

          <label>Password</label>
          <p-password name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" [feedback]="false" [toggleMask]="true"></p-password>

          <p-button label="Login" class="button-login" (onClick)="login()">
          </p-button>

  </div>
```

I want that the "Login" to be clicked when the Enter key is pressed. I have tried wrapping the content on a form, using (keypress.enter), on other similar things that I found but I have not been able to make any of them works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add event `keydown.enter` on your wrapping `div` like:

```
<div class="Login" (keydown.enter)="login()">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="username" pInputText [(ngModel)]="username" />

      <label>Password</label>
      <p-password name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" [feedback]="false" [toggleMask]="true"></p-password>

      <p-button label="Login" class="button-login" (onClick)="login()">
      </p-button>
</div>
```